# Camera started but can't see preview, Camera2 androidx compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, androidx, android-camera2

I have been trying to make cameraX2 to work with compose for couple of days now.

The issue is that it seems like camera starts. It shows green label indicating that the camera is capturing, but preview does not work. After navigating back one image from camera is brifly visible during transition.

I have attached screenshots below so you see how it works.

Camera2 version is 1.2.1

```
private const val cameraVersion="1.2.1"
const val camera="androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$cameraVersion";
const val cameraLifecycle="androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$cameraVersion"
const val cameraView="androidx.camera:camera-view:$cameraVersion"
```

Composable

```
@Composable
@Destination
fun TakePictureScreen(
    viewModel: TakePictureViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {


    val lensFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    var cameraInit = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
    val previewView = remember { PreviewView(context) }
    val imageCapture: ImageCapture = remember { ImageCapture.Builder().build() }
    val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(lensFacing)
        .build()


    val cameraPermissionResultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
        onResult = { isGranted ->
            viewModel.onPermissionResult(
                permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                isGranted = isGranted
            )
        }
    )

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        cameraPermissionResultLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(lensFacing) {
        val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            lifecycleOwner,
            cameraSelector,
            preview
        )

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
        delay(2000)
        cameraInit.value=true
    }

    if (cameraInit.value) {
        Icon(
            tint = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.can_location),
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.take_photo)
        )
        AndroidView(
            factory = { previewView }, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            update = {
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

First screenshots, after that I press the camera button and the app navigates to different composable screen.

[image]

This is the composable where the camera should be rendered.
You can see top right corner there is a green dot indicating camera is running.

[image]

After I navigate back using a gesture, the camera shows one frame as the app is transitioning to the previous screen

[image]

Comment: try wrapping Preview and CameraSelector with `remember`, they gets recreated on each recomposition right now

Comment: @PhilDukhov Thanks for suggestion mate, it does not work with remember wrapped around neither of them. Makes sense cause they are just builders for objects. I have no idea why it doesnt work :_(  Considering just replacing it with fragment...

Comment: I tried running your code and it works fine to me. I had to update it to run in an empty project - here's my version https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/a6230cfebdf665f6dda54791ee90206d. Maybe it's related to your navigation system. Make sure you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question

Answer (score 0):

I will post it here maybe someone will have the same problem.

I have figured out that the problem was with a style of the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/almost_black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/almost_black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

After removing, it stared to work.

```
    <item name="android:background">@color/almost_black</item>
```